# How to set width of GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a JPanel and i am adding gridbagLayouts to it.
but sometimes the gridbaglayout is not big enough to show the title of a tree
like this:

[image]

how can i set the width of this ?

```
    JPanel F_panel = new JPanel();
    String Fs_desc = MpaResourceBundle.getString(Ps_label, Constants.RB_PACKAGE);
    String Fs_dir = P_type.getRepoDir();
    String Fs_title = Fs_desc + " (" + Fs_dir + ")";
    F_panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(Fs_title));
    F_panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints F_constr = new GridBagConstraints();
    F_constr.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    F_constr.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    F_constr.gridx = 0;
    F_constr.gridy = 0;

    for (PluginID F_pid : dataHolder.getAllPluginIDs())
    {
        COSDependencyMetaInfoTree F_cosDepMITree = new COSDependencyMetaInfoTree(P_type,
                null,
                dataHolder.getMasterCOSLogObjectNames(),
                F_pid,
                dataHolder.getRepoObjectOwners(),
                null,
                P_coll);
        if (F_cosDepMITree.getRowCount() > 1)
        {
            P_treeList.add(F_cosDepMITree);
            F_panel.add(F_cosDepMITree, F_constr);
            F_constr.gridy++;
        }
    }

    if (F_panel.getComponents().length > 0)
    {
        add(F_panel, P_gbc);
        P_gbc.gridy++;
    }
```

Comment: `weightx`, `ipadx`, `fill` come to mind.  The problem is more likely that the requirements of the `TitleBorder` are not considered when calculating the preferred size of the component (other the insets)

Comment: yes, how can i fix this with TitleBorder ?

Comment: *"sometimes the gridbaglayout is not big enough to show the title.."*  If you're referring to the `TitledBorder` note that that is a commonly known behaviour. (shrugs).  If it is vital to show the text, I'd recommend putting it in a `JLabel`.

Comment: i have added the code, can i set the size of the TitleBorder ?

Comment: @seriously Essentially, no.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set a tooltip for the panel to display the entire border title when the mouse hovers over the title:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TitledBorderTest
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        UIManager.getDefaults().put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
        Border lowerEtched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
        String titleText = "Long title that will be truncated in the panel";
        TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lowerEtched, titleText);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Border border = getBorder();

                if (border instanceof TitledBorder)
                {
                    TitledBorder tb = (TitledBorder)border;
                    FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics( getFont() );
                    int titleWidth = fm.stringWidth(tb.getTitle()) + 20;
                    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, titleWidth, fm.getHeight());
                    return bounds.contains(e.getPoint()) ? super.getToolTipText() : null;
                }

                return super.getToolTipText(e);
            }
        };
        panel.setBorder( title );
        panel.setToolTipText(title.getTitle());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```